# Using \verb with a command parameter

Tags: tex-core, verbatim

I wanted to build a little command to show me the different lengths of spaces. Sadly I am having problems with \verb accepting my parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
% this works:
$I\ I$ \verb|'\ '|

% interpretes the spaces
%\newcommand{\genLine}[1]{$I#1I$ & \texttt{'#1'}\\}

% doesn't work with command
%\newcommand{\genLine}[1]{$I#1I$ & \verb|'#1'|\\}

% package listings has problems with the '\'
\lstset{language=Tex}
\lstMakeShortInline{|}
\newcommand{\genLine}[1]{$I#1I$ & \lstinline|'#1'|\\}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    Beispiel & Befehl \\ \hline
    \genLine{\,}
    \genLine{\:}
    \genLine{\;}
    \genLine{$ $}
    \genLine{\ }
    \genLine{\enspace}
    \genLine{\quad}
    \genLine{\qquad}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```